# C++ class dll with CUDA member?

Tags: c++, class, dll, cuda

I have a C++ class-based dll. I'd like to convert some of the class members to CUDA based operation.

**I am using VS2012, WINDOWS 7, CUDA6.5, sm_20;**

Say the original SuperProjector.h file is like:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) SuperProjector 
{
public:
    SuperProjector(){}; 
    ~SuperProjector(){};
    void sumVectors(float* c, float* a, float* b, int N);
};
```

and the original `sumVector()` function in SuperProjector.cpp

```
void SuperProjector::sumVectors(float* c, float* a, float* b, int N)
{
    for (int n = 1; n < N; b++)
        c[n] = a[n] + b[n];
}
```

I am stuck on how I should convert sumVector() to CUDA. Specifically:

1. I read some posts saying add `__global__ __device__` keywords in front
   of class members will work, but so I need to change the suffix of
   the cpp file to cu?
2. I also tried to create a cuda project from the beginning, but it seems VS2012 does not give me the option of creating a dll once I chose to create a CUDA project.

I am very confused what is the best way to convert some of the members of tthis C++ class based dll into some CUDA kernel functions. I appreciate anyone can offer some ideas, or better with some very simple examples.

Comment: The really short answer is that you can't directly convert C++ member functions into kernels because kernels (`__global__` functions) cannot be class members in the CUDA object model.

Comment: @talonmies ok.....so is there anyway I can indirectly do this? for example, creating a cuda class, then convert it to a dll? or ....embed some kernels in the class members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create CUDA project, let's call it `cudaSuperProjector` and add two files `SuperProjector.cu` and `SuperProjector.h`

   **`cudaSuperProjector.h`**

   ```
   class __declspec(dllexport) cudaSuperProjector {
   public:
       cudaSuperProjector(){ }
       ~cudaSuperProjector(){ }
       void sumVectors(float* c, float* a, float* b, int N);
   };
   ```

   **`cudaSuperProjector.cu`**

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   #include "cuda_runtime.h"
   #include "device_launch_parameters.h"

   #include "cudaSuperProjector.h"

   __global__ void addKernel(float *c, const float *a, const float *b) {
       int i = threadIdx.x;
       c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
   }

   // Helper function for using CUDA to add vectors in parallel.
   cudaError_t addWithCuda(float *c, const float *a, const float *b, unsigned int size) {
       float *dev_a = 0;
       float *dev_b = 0;
       float *dev_c = 0;
       cudaError_t cudaStatus;

       // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
       cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);

       // Allocate GPU buffers for three vectors (two input, one output)    .
       cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, size * sizeof(float));
       cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size * sizeof(float));
       cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, size * sizeof(float));

       // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
       cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
       cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

       // Launch a kernel on the GPU with one thread for each element.
       addKernel << <1, size >> >(dev_c, dev_a, dev_b);
       // Check for any errors launching the kernel
       cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
       // cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
       // any errors encountered during the launch.
       cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();

       // Copy output vector from GPU buffer to host memory.
       cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
       return cudaStatus;
   }

   void cudaSuperProjector::sumVectors(float* c, float* a, float* b, int N) {
       cudaError_t cudaStatus = addWithCuda(c, a, b, N);
       if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
           fprintf(stderr, "cudaSuperProjector::sumVectors failed!");
       }
   }
   ```

   Note: In properties of file `cudaSuperProjector.cu` `Item Type` should be `CUDA C/C++`.
2. Go to properties of the project and in `General` set value of `Configuration Type` to `Dynamic Library (.dll)`. Now everything for creating library is ready. Compile this project and in output folder you will find `cudaSuperProjector.dll` and `cudaSuperProjector.lib`. Create directory `cudaSuperProjector\lib` and copy `cudaSuperProjector.dll` and `cudaSuperProjector.lib` there. Also create `cudaSuperProjector\include` and copy `cudaSuperProjector.h` in it.
3. Create another `Visual C++` project, let's call it `SuperProjector`. Add file `SuperProjector.cpp` to the project.

   **`SuperProjector.cpp`**

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   #include "cudaSuperProjector/cudaSuperProjector.h"

   int main(int argc, char** argv) {

       float a[6] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
       float b[6] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
       float c[6] = {  };

       cudaSuperProjector csp;
       csp.sumVectors(c, a, b, 6);
       printf("c = {%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f}\n",
              c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4], c[5]);

       return 0;
   }
   ```
4. In properties of the project add path to the `dll` and `lib` files to the `VC++ Directories -> Library Directories`, for example `D:\cudaSuperProjector\lib;`, in `VC++ Directories -> Include Directories` add path to the header, for example `D:\cudaSuperProjector\include;`. Then go to the `Linker -> Input` and add `cudaSuperProjector.lib;`.
5. Now your project should compile fine, but when you run it it will show you the error

   > The program can't start because cudaSuperProjector.dll is missing from
   >   your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

   You need to copy `cudaSuperProjector.dll` to the output folder of the project, so it will be under the same folder as `SuperProjector.exe`. You can do it manually or add

   ```
   copy D:\cudaSuperProjector\lib\cudaSuperProjector.dll $(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\
   ```

   in `Build Events -> Post-Build Events -> Command Line`,
   where `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\` is output path for solution (see `Configuration Properties -> General -> Output Directory`).

Comment: Thanks!! This is terrific!